# How can I check user input if it is valid or invalid input?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
    String word[] = { "apple" };

    char wordguess[] = word[random.nextInt(word.length)].toCharArray();
    int totalOfGuesses = wordguess.length;
    char[] userGuess = new char[totalOfGuesses]; // save the users input

    System.out.print("Please input your guess : ");
    char input = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
}
```

How can I check user input if it is valid or invalid input?
then, if it is valid, store it in an array called value
otherwise, save the character in the array called invalid.
thank for help

For example:
valid:_ _ _ _ _  invalid:_ _ _ _ _
Please input your guess : a

For example:
valid: a _ _ _ _  invalid:_ _ _ _ _
Please input your guess : a

For example:
valid: a _ _ _ _  invalid:b _ _ _ _
Please input your guess : b

For example:
valid: a _ _ _ _  invalid:b _ _ _ _ 
Please input your guess : b (will not save b again)

Comment: by validating it

Comment: Also, try to make question for one problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy and you could've found this on google. Always check when you're expecting an user input:

```
if (input != null)
//store it
```

Remember to check your scanner as well.

Comment: How to check input if equal to array

Comment: @SHINGHIMLEE  
"input.equals()". Remember to set my answer as the correct one if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Make a `set` and add all invalid letters inside it.

In each input you have to loop over this set and check if the input `char` is one was entered before.

Also, use `while` to make an infinite loop until the user input a valid `char`

Consider this simple code to solve part of your problem, you have to continue...

This code will continue take input from user until he input a valid `char`.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);) {
        boolean invalidInput = true;
        Set<Character> invalidChars = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));

        WhileLoop: while (invalidInput) {
            System.out.print("Please input your guess (one letter): ");
            String inputLine = scanner.nextLine();

            if (inputLine == null || inputLine.trim().isEmpty() || !String.valueOf(inputLine.charAt(0)).matches("[a-zA-Z]")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, Please enter a letter (A to Z).");
                continue;
            }

            for (char c : invalidChars) {
                if (inputLine.charAt(0) == c) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid latter, You have entered this letter before, choose another one.");
                    invalidChars.add(c);
                    continue WhileLoop;
                }
            }
            invalidInput = false;
        }
    }
}
```